# Pack and unpack multiple integers into and from an Uint64

Tags: c#, .net, int

Need to pack and unpack the following into an UInt64
UInt25
UInt5
UInt7
UInt27

Have the following for packing and unpacking UInt27 and UInt5 to from UInt32
But I cannot get past 2
My background is math (not computer science)

```
UInt32 highlow;
UInt32 high;
byte  low;
int two27 = (Int32)Math.Pow(2, 27);
for (UInt32 i = 0; i < two27; i++)
{
    highlow = ((UInt32)i) << 5;
    high = highlow >> 5;
    if (high != i)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("high wrong A " + high.ToString() + " " + i.ToString());
    }
    for (byte j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        highlow = (((UInt32)i) << 5) | j;
        high = highlow >> 5;
        if (high != i)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("high wrong B " + high.ToString() + " " + i.ToString());
        }
        low = (byte)(highlow & 0x1f);
        if (low != j)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("low wrong " + low.ToString() + " " + j.ToString());
        }
    }               
}
```

Code based on accepted answer (did not test the full loop the i27 loop got to 2)

```
UInt32 bits27;
UInt32 bits25;
UInt32 bits7;
UInt32 bits5;
UInt32 int27 = (UInt32)Math.Pow(2,27);
UInt32 int25 = (UInt32)Math.Pow(2,25);
UInt32 int7  = (UInt32)Math.Pow(2,7);
UInt32 int5  = (UInt32)Math.Pow(2,5);
UInt64 packed;
//ulong packed = (bits27) | ((ulong)bits25 << 27) | ((ulong)bits7 << 52) | ((ulong)bits5 << 59);
for             (UInt32 i27 = 0; i27 < int27; i27++)
{
    for         (UInt32 i25 = 0; i25 < int25; i25++)
    {
        for     (UInt32  i7 = 0;  i7 <  int7; i7++)
        {
            for (UInt32  i5 = 0;  i5 <  int5; i5++)
            {
                packed = (UInt64)(i27) | ((UInt64)i25 << 27) | ((UInt64)i7 << 52) | ((UInt64)i5 << 59);

                bits27 = (UInt32)(packed & ((1 << 27) - 1));
                bits25 = (UInt32)((packed >> 27) & ((1 << 25) - 1));
                bits7 =  (UInt32)((packed >> 52) & ((1 << 7) - 1));
                bits5 =  (UInt32)((packed >> 59) & ((1 << 5) - 1));
                if (bits27 != i27) Debug.WriteLine("bits27 != i27");
                if (bits25 != i25) Debug.WriteLine("bits25 != i25");
                if (bits7  != i7)  Debug.WriteLine("bits7  !=  i7");
                if (bits5  != i5)  Debug.WriteLine("bits5  !=  i5");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might look into using a `union` of a Boolean array and a uint64 - or use `long int` (is that 64 bit on your machine ) and just do shift and add...

Comment: You are looping `i`, a `uint16‘, to 2^27. Not your only problem, but not gonna work... And if a result overflows the outcome is undefined, so use types that can hold the result!

Comment: @Floris Agree i should be Unint32.  That is a problem with the test.  What about that pack and unpack does not work?

Comment: You need 64 bit, not 32, to get things to fit. When you cast things to `UInt32` you throw away the top 32 bits. The currently accepted answer doesn't guaranteed that. If your compiler defines a uint64 type (or equivalent), all the better. If it doesn't, add it yourself with a `#define uint64 (unsigned long long)`.

Comment: @Floris when I hover on ulong I get UInt64.  I updated what I think is the accepted answer.  Do you feel that is a correct answer?

Comment: From what you say I conclude that, onn your platform / compiler, ulong is UInt64. That means the accepted answer (which is clean, and actually follows the suggestion I made in my original comment quite closely) will work very well for you - you were right to accept it. But I would like to see @BenVoigt improve the answer to make explicit that `ulong` === `UInt64`, as that is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Floris It also concerned me and I had tested with the posted code update before I even saw your comment.

Comment: @Floris: [It is guaranteed.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)

Comment: @Blam: Floris's comments assume you are using C++, where the types are implementation-dependent.  In C# (or Java) there is no such concern.

Comment: @benvoigt you are right I should have looked at the tag more carefully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shift operators are the right solution, but note that they won't automatically make the result wider than the inputs -- you need to cast the input.

Pack:

```
ulong packed = (bits27) | ((ulong)bits25 << 27) | ((ulong)bits7 << 52) | ((ulong)bits5 << 59);
```

Unpack:

```
bits27 = (uint) (packed        & ((1 << 27) - 1));
bits25 = (uint)((packed >> 27) & ((1 << 25) - 1));
bits7  = (uint)((packed >> 52) & ((1 <<  7) - 1));
bits5  = (uint)((packed >> 59) & ((1 <<  5) - 1));
```

Comment: I will test. If that works it is soo cool.  I do not know know what you mean by cast the input?

Comment: `(ulong) bits25` is a cast

Comment: This works on a platform in which a `unsigned long` is 64 bits long. The standard guarantees that `long` is 32 bits. You need `unsigned long long` (specified in C99) to guarantee 64 bits.

Comment: It was not part of the question.  But when I took it to 32 it broke as shift assumes signed Int32.  UInt64 u1 = (UInt64)1; ((u1 << 32) - 1); fixed it.  ((1 << 31) - 1) threw a compiler error is how I figured it out.

Comment: @Blam: Yes, I definitely am using cast-to-ulong whenever a shift needs to use more than the low 32 bits.

Comment: So how could I adapt this to work with signed ints for input and output? I tried the following:

`ulong segmentId = (uint)x | ((ulong)y << 32);  
int ux = (int)(segmentId & ((1 << 32) - 1));  
int uy = (int)((segmentId >> 32) & ((1 << 32) - 1));  
Debug.Log("Unpacked x = " + ux.ToString() + ", y = " + uy.ToString());`  

But the output after attempting to unpack is always x = 0, y = 0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be far easier to convert the numbers to binary, pad or truncate to the correct length, concatenate them and then construct your 64-bit type from binary.

```
var packedInt64 = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToString(ui25, 2).PadLeft(25, '0') +
                                  Convert.ToString(ui5, 2).PadLeft(5, '0') +
                                  Convert.ToString(ui7, 2).PadLeft(7, '0') +
                                  Convert.ToString(ui27, 2).PadLeft(2, '0'), 2);
```

To unpack:

```
var binary = Convert.ToString(packedInt64, 2);
ui25 = Convert.ToUInt32(binary.Substring(0, 24));
ui5 = Convert.ToUInt32(binary.Substring(24, 5));
etc.
```

Comment: Not only is this less efficient than shifting, the code is harder to read as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's definitely far less efficient, but I would argue it's far easier to read.  Looking at the code example above, it would take a long time to figure out what it's doing if you didn't already know.  It also took a SO question to debug it, where it's fairly easy to debug this code.

Comment: @BenVoigt I hadn't loaded your answer yet - I agree that your code is much nicer than mine.  I was hoping to convert to something more like a bool array than use strings - this is the best I could make this approach look.

Comment: @Blam I've added an example of unpack code, but if you understand Ben's code I would probably use it with an explanatory comment.

Comment: You're right, it might not be as clear what Ben's code is doing at first glance. But that's easily fixed using a comment or perhaps just the name of a method. Once you know what the goal is, the code is instantly obvious.